# REST endpoints in Spring Integration make messaging channels multithreaded

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have a very simple  Spring Boot application, which provides a couple of restful endpoints and this is supposed to drive a sftp file being uploaded to a sftp server. My requirement is that if there is more than one file, the files should be queued. I expected to achieve this with the default behaviour of the sftp spring integration workflow, as i read that DirectChannel automatically queues files. To test the behaviour I do the following:

1. Send a big file, blocking the channel for a while by calling an endpoint.
2. Send a smaller file by calling an endpoint.

Expected result: the smaller file is queued onto a channel and is processed after the uploading of the bigger file is finished.
Actual result: A new connection to sftp server is opened and the smaller file is uploaded there without being queued, while the bigger file continues transmission.

There are two files in my application:

DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser("tester");
        factory.setPassword("password");
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("/"));
        return handler;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface MyGateway {

         @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
         void sendToSftp(File file);
    }
}
```

DemoController.java

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    MyGateway gateway;

    @RequestMapping("/sendFile")
    public void sendFile() {
        File file = new File("C:/smallFile.txt");
        gateway.sendToSftp(file);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/sendBigFile")
    public void sendBigFile() {
        File file = new File("D:/bigFile.zip");
        gateway.sendToSftp(file);
    }
}
```

I'm a complete newbie to spring and i'm not sure entirely that my sftp channels get created here properly, my guess would be that a new one gets created every time i do a sendToSftp call. Any help on how to achieve the queue behaviour in this case would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a queue here because each HTTP request is performed in its own thread. Right, you maybe queued there anyway when the pool of http threads is exhausted, but that doesn't look in your simple use-case with just two requests.

You can achieve a queue behavior there anyway, but you should declare your `toSftpChannel` as a `QueueChannel` bean.

That way downstream process will always be performed on the same thread and the next message is pulled from the queue exactly after the first one.

See [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#polling-consumer) for more information.

**UPDATE**

Since you use `FtpMessageHandler` which is one-way component, but you still need some reply to the MVC controller's methods, only the way to do that is to have a `@Gateway` method with non-`void` return and of course we need to send the reply somehow.

For this purpose I suggest to use `PublishSubscribeChannel`:

```
@Bean
@BridgeTo
public MessageChannel toSftpChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
@Order(0)
public MessageHandler handler() {
    SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("/"));
    return handler;
}
```

This way we have two subscribers to the `toSftpChannel`. With the `@Order(0)` we ensure that `@ServiceActivator` is the first subscriber since we need to perform SFTP transfer first. With the `@BridgeTo` we add a second `BridgeHandler` to the same `PublishSubscribeChannel`. Its purpose is just to get a `replyChannel` header and send the request message there. Since we don't use any threading the `BridgeHandler` will be performed exactly after finish of the transfer to the SFTP.

Of course instead of `BridgeHandler` you can have any other `@ServiceActivator` or `@Transfromer` to return as a reply not a request `File`, but anything else. For example:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
@Order(1)
public String transferComplete(File payload) {
    return "The SFTP transfer complete for file: " + payload;
}
```

Comment: Hi, so i have a question building up on that. How can i make sendToSftp return some status of the transfer? I tried changing void to String or object, adding reply channels or an error channel to the messaging gateway with no result, some help would be very appreciated

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: How can i capture exceptions? I try contacting either a non existing server or folder without permissions or so and get a massive stack trace which seems to show a MessagingException at the top. I added throws MessagingException on sendToSftp in the gateway and surrounded with try catch in the DemoController, but it seems like sendToSftp doesn't return at all if an exception occurs

Comment: Consider to use `errorChannel` on the gateway. Nobody is going to return if there is an exception. That is just Java first of all...

Comment: Sorry, by doesn't return i meant it neither returns nor throws anything, it just doesn't continue at all

Comment: Hm. Looks like you don't show something else in your configuration. You might have some thread shifting. That's only the clue how exceptions are not thrown to the Gateway level.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for such a late reply, i got carried away a little. Yes, you were right, i had a queue channel implemented and it seems like with this implementation it was getting lost somewhere among the threads. Looks to be throwing an exception as expected with a default channel. Thanks for the helpful comments