# Spring Integration: how to access the returned values from last Subscriber

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm trying to implement a SFTP File Upload of 2 Files which has to happen in a certain order - first a pdf file and after successfull upload of that an text file with meta information about the pdf.

I followed the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362706/rest-endpoints-in-spring-integration-make-messaging-channels-multithreaded) thread, but can't get it to work properly.

My Spring Boot Configuration:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    final Properties jschProps = new Properties();
    jschProps.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    jschProps.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,password");
    factory.setSessionConfig(jschProps);

    factory.setHost(sftpHost);
    factory.setPort(sftpPort);
    factory.setUser(sftpUser);
    if (sftpPrivateKey != null) {
        factory.setPrivateKey(sftpPrivateKey);
        factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(sftpPrivateKeyPassphrase);
    } else {
        factory.setPassword(sftpPasword);
    }
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}

@Bean
@BridgeTo
public MessageChannel toSftpChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}


@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
@Order(0)
public MessageHandler handler() {
    final SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(sftpRemoteDirectory));
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> {
        if (message.getPayload() instanceof byte[]) {
            return (String) message.getHeaders().get("filename");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
        }
    });
    return handler;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
@Order(1)
public String transferComplete(@Payload byte[] file, @Header("filename") String filename) {
    return "The SFTP transfer complete for file: " + filename;
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface UploadGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    String upload(@Payload byte[] file, @Header("filename") String filename);

}
```

My Test Case:

```
final String pdfStatus = uploadGateway.upload(content, documentName);
log.info("Upload of {} completed, {}.", documentName, pdfStatus);
```

From the return of the Gateway upload call i expect to get the String confirming the upload e.g. "The SFTP transfer complete for file:..." but I get the the returned content of the uploaded File in byte[]:

```
Upload of 123456789.1.pdf completed, 37,80,68,70,45,49,46,54,13,37,-30,-29,-49,-45,13,10,50,55,53,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,60,60,47,76,105,110,101,97,114,105,122,101,100,32,49,47,76,32,50,53,52,55,49,48,47,79,32,50,55,55,47,69,32,49,49,49,55,55,55,47,78,32,49,47,84,32,50,53,52,51,53,57,47,72,32,91,32,49,49,57,55,32,53,51,55,93,62,62,13,101,110,100,111,98,106,13,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,13,10,52,55,49,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,60,60,47,68,101,99,111,100,101,80,97,114,109,115,60,60,47,67,111,108,117,109,110,115,32,53,47,80,114,101,100,105,99,116,111,114,32,49,50,62,62,47,70,105,108,116,101,114,47,70,108,97,116,101,68,101,99,111,100,101,47,73,68,91,60,57,66,53,49,56,54,69,70,53,66,56,66,49,50,52,49,65,56,50,49,55,50,54,56,65,65,54,52,65,57,70,54,62,60,68,52,50,68,51,55,54,53,54,65,67,48,55,54,52,65,65,53,52,66,52,57,51,50,56,52,56,68,66 etc.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `@Order(0)`  doesn't work together with the `@Bean`.

To fix it you should do this in that bean definition istead:

```
final SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
handler.setOrder(0);
```

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans) for more info:

> When using these annotations on consumer `@Bean` definitions, if the bean definition returns an appropriate `MessageHandler` (depending on the annotation type), attributes such as `outputChannel`, `requiresReply` etc, must be set on the `MessageHandler` `@Bean` definition itself.

In other words: if you can use setter, you have to. We don't process annotations for this case because there is no guarantee what should get a precedence. So, to avoid such a confuse we have left for you only setters choice.

**UPDATE**

I see your problem and it is here:

```
@Bean
@BridgeTo
public MessageChannel toSftpChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}
```

That is confirmed by the logs:

```
Adding {bridge:dmsSftpConfig.toSftpChannel.bridgeTo} as a subscriber to the 'toSftpChannel' channel
Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@b3d0f7.toSftpChannel' has 3 subscriber(s).
started dmsSftpConfig.toSftpChannel.bridgeTo
```

So, you really have one more subscriber to that `toSftpChannel` and it is a `BridgeHandler` with an output to the `replyChannel` header. And a default order is like `private volatile int order = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;` this one becomes as a first subscriber and exactly this one returns you that `byte[]` just because it is a `payload` of request.

You need to decide if you really need such a bridge. There is no workaround for the `@Order` though...

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but nothing changed in the output. The files are uploaded and the return string from the gateway's upload method still contains the whole byte array of the uploaded document... any other suggestions on how to check the status of the upload?

Comment: OK. Are you sure your they is no any other subscriber to that `toSftpChannel`? Would you mind to turn on `DEBUG` logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` category and share with us here logs to be sure how the message is traveling after reaching `toSftpChannel`? Thanks

Comment: sure, Here is the log output [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8mwz1kcc7nt2doy/AAAp57dubrd8fpXBrzosdhJra?dl=0)..Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful. See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that was indeed the problem. Do you maybe also have a suggestion, on how to wrap the 2 file uploads in one transaction using spring-integration so that if the second upload fails, the first upload can be deleted? Or is it better if I create a new topic for that purpose? Regards, Rok

Comment: The same `@MessagingGateway` with the `@Transactional` and `splitter` for two files downstream. But that is a different story. Agreed ?