# Request-reply for SFTP in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm trying to implement some kind of request-reply feature for SFTP connection in Spring. The logic consists of the following pieces:

1. Prepare file
2. Send a file via SFTP
3. Hold on the processing and await file response (listen to same SFTP with some timeout)
4. Once response file is found on SFTP, stop listening, transfer the file, process the data and resume the processing. If timeout was reached, the processing should resume without doing operations on the file (a specific status would be set poining there's no response).

I'm quite new to Spring Integration and I'm not sure if there's any build-in request-reply logic I could use instead of the below solution. My idea for 2. was to send a file using `inputChannel` and `@MessagingGateway` as per the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html) and this piece of code is working as expected. Once the file is sent, I'm trying to handle 3. and 4. by manual registration of `inboundAdapter` and implementing a file transformation in `handle` method. However with this approach I would face issues with resuming processing stopped after sending the file, as the logic would proceed and `handle` method would be in a separate thread. Additional issue is that `handle` method is called for each directory on local, not only if expected remove file found.

Sending a file:

```
   @Bean
    public SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        //... setters
        return new CachingSessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("/remoteDir");
        handler.setFileNameGenerator(//...);
        return handler;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface UploadGateway{

         @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
         void upload(File file);

    }
```

Listening to a response:

```
public void createSftpListener(String fileName){
    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
    .from(
         Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory)
             .preserveTimestamp(true)
             .remoteDirectory("/remoteDir")
             .regexFilter(fileName)
             .localDirectory("/localDir"),
         e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
               .autoStartup(true)
              .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10000))
         )
     .handle(m -> {         //executed for each subdirectory of localDir, not only if fileName found in remoteDir, as I would expected
           service.processFile(fileName);
           this.flowContext.remove(fileName); //stop listening
           })
     .get();
   
  IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration register = 
                    this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(fileName).register(); //register with id equals to unique fileName

}
```

Processing logic skeleton:

```
public Status process(){
    prepareFile();
    uploadGateway.sendFile();
    createSftpListener(); //should listen until file received or until timeout reached 
    return finalLogic(); //should be executed once filen received or timeout reached
}
```

EDIT:

```
    @MessagingGateway
    public interface DownloadGateway{

         @Gateway(requestChannel = "fromSftpChannel")
         File get(String filePath);

    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromSftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler handlerFrom() {
        SftpOutboundGateway handler = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "get", "payload");
        handler.setLocalDirectory("/localDir/reply");
        handler.setAdviceChain(Arrays.asList(replyRetryAdvice()));
        return handler;
    }
```

EDIT2:

```
    @Bean
    public PublishSubscribeChannel pubSubChannel(){
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubSubChannel")
    @Order(0) //seems ok
    public MessageHandler handlerTo() {
        SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
        handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("/remoteDir");
        handler.setFileNameGenerator(//...);
        //  handler.setOrder(0); //doesn't keep the order? 
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubSubChannel")
    @Order(1) //seems ok
    public MessageHandler handlerFrom() {
        SftpOutboundGateway handler = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "get", "'/remoteDir/'+payload.getName().replace('.txt','.out')");
        handler.setLocalDirectory("/localDir/reply");
        handler.setAdviceChain(Arrays.asList(replyRetryAdvice()));
        //  handler.setOrder(1); //doesn't keep the order? 
        return handler;
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface PubSubGateway{
         @Gateway(requestChannel = "pubSubChannel")
         File reqRep(File requestFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to look into an `SftpOutboundGateway` in combination with a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` with some backoff in between retries. So, after sending a file via `SftpMessageHandler`, you proceed to the `SftpOutboundGateway` with that retry loop until a reply the is returned by the `GET` operation. For this scenario to work your `toSftpChannel` must be a `PublishSubscribeChannel`: the same message with an original file would be sent to the SFTP and sub-flow with an `SftpOutboundGateway` to wait for a reply file. This way an original `@MessagingGateway` would be blocked until all the retry attempts are exhausted. you probably would need also to look into some other than `void` return from your gateway method.

Comment: Thank you, I've started looking into the solution and created @MessagingGateway DownloadGateway for SftpOutboundGateway 'fromSftpChannel' where I set adviceChain. I'm only not sure about the part: "same message with an original file would be sent to the SFTP and sub-flow with an SftpOutboundGateway to wait for a reply file.". Couldn't I first call UploadGateway.upload and then retry DownloadGateway.get until the file with expected name is found, should I relate the invocations somehow?

Comment: That's exactly what I explained with `PublishSubscribeChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel. You just use this channel for the `SftpMessageHandler` endpoint to upload. And then you use the same channel for `SftpOutboundGateway` with a retry advice to download reply file. The whole flow will be blocked until your `SftpOutboundGateway` answers or re-throws an exception.

Comment: I edited the post to include SftpOutboundGateway config. I'm trying to understand if PublishSubscribeChannel is necessary or if I could simply call 'upload' and 'get'

Comment: Well, that also possible. So, you have different APIs on a gateway: `upload` and `get`. If you wish to do that, that's OK. Not sure though why would one need two separate top-level APIs: it was not obvious from your original question...

Comment: I've updated the post for the solution using PublishSubscribeChannel. I hope this is something you had in mind. It requires adjustment for GET expression to listen for a specific filename. Not sure if there's a need to pass File or if the other approach would not be easier. Also need to learn more about error handling.

I was also wondering whether I could use SftpOutboundGateway PUT instead of SftpMessageHandler to upload a file, but I think it is returning String which could be confusing if the final return type should be File.

Comment: Yes, you can use `PUT` instead and it returns for us a remote file path. That way you would need to chain two `SftpOutboundGateway` instances instead of a `PublishSubscribeChannel`. Nevertheless what you have so far is really what I had in mind.

Comment: Hm, what is the reason I couldn't use PublishSubscribeChannel? Sorry, I'm pretty new to Spring Integration.. I'm going to accept the answer, but have one more question.From what I understand the messages are set one by one,not at the same time, so I need to set order to make sure I send a file first and then listen to the reply. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991453/spring-integration-how-to-access-the-returned-values-from-last-subscriber saying that I should rather use setter but it doesn't seem to keep the order, while @Order seems to be working fine. Please the the update

Comment: It works fine because in the order how you define those handler beans. Yes, you have to use a setter on those `AbstractMessageHandler` instances.